# Animations for algorithms and data structures?

Tags: algorithm

Is there an application that can animate graph algorithms?

I find it much easier to understand a graph algorithm by watching animations. It would be nice if there is an application that can animate some common graph algorithms.

**Edit**

Any type of animation would be much appreciated. But it would be more desirable to have user interactions (e.g. data input, control of speed, play back).

A list of algorithms here:

1. Breadth-first search: http://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~cfs/472_html/AI_SEARCH/SearchAnimations.html
2. Depth-first search: http://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~cfs/472_html/AI_SEARCH/SearchAnimations.html
3. Dijkstra: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~aaw/HFHuang/DijkstraStart.html
4. minimum spanning tree;
5. bipartite match;
6. maximum flow problem;
7. binary tree operations;
8. red-black tree;
9. B-tree operations: http://slady.net/java/bt/view.php, http://ats.oka.nu/b-tree/b-tree.html
10. disjoint set.

Comment: Google it like this "Dijkstra applet" and you will get a lot of animations

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- BTree:
  http://ats.oka.nu/b-tree/b-tree.html
- BFS & DFS: http://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~cfs/472_html/AI_SEARCH/SearchAnimations.html
- Dijkstra: http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/combinatorica/animations/dijkstra.html
- MST: http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/combinatorica/animations/mst.html
- Red Black Tree: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~achou/cs102/examples/bst_animation/RedBlackTree-Example.html
- Skip list: http://iamwww.unibe.ch/~wenger/DA/SkipList/
- 2-3-4 tree: http://www.cs.unm.edu/~rlpm/499/ttft.html

I found a list of different algorithms with their animations but many seem to require Animal (a software for showing them).

- Animal Download Link: http://www.algoanim.info/Animal2/?q=taxonomy/term/7
- Visualizations: http://www.animal.ahrgr.de/animations.php3?lang=e

Comment: Excellent stuff! Thank you. If you don't mind, I'll later merge your answers into the question so that other people would see it more easily.

Answer (score 4):

I found another good website (Interactive Visualisation). It contains visualisation for all the data structures.

http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Algorithms.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Wiki and google is your friend.

There is a program , LEDA, which you can write some code and animate the graphs, they do have some samples as well.

http://www.algorithmic-solutions.com/leda/

native language is C++ but you can port some java to it as well.

Moreover, Flex has several libraries on graphs, you can see their demos and samples.

Answer (score 1):

Skip list: http://iamwww.unibe.ch/~wenger/DA/SkipList/
2-3-4 tree: http://www.cs.unm.edu/~rlpm/499/ttft.html

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has some:

e.g.:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm (on the left)

New here, so I can't put in any more hyperlinks (remove space after http://):

**BFS**: http:// en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#How_it_works 
**Bipartite Matching** (interactive demo): http:// www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/cs423/matching/matching.html